# Stop file chooser key event propagation to the (parent) stage in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I need to listen to key events in stage but not when the `FileChooser` is displayed.

Is there a way to stop `KeyEvent` (e.g. `Esc` key is pressed.) propagation to (parent) `Stage`, when `FileChooser` is displayed?

OR

Detect that the `KeyEvent` is propagated from `FileChooser`?

```
class KeyEventTest extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
  {
    Button browseBtn = new Button("Browse File System");
    browseBtn.setOnAction(ae ->
      {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
      });

    stage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(browseBtn), 500, 200));
    stage.setTitle("Test");

    stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent ->
      {
        // Do not trigger when Esc key is pressed on FileChooser
        KeyCode keyCode = keyEvent.getCode();
        System.out.println(keyCode);
      });

    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: I had thought we could simply remove the `EventFilter` when showing the `FileChooser` and re-add it when that closes, but in my tests, it still passes the `KeyEvent` to the parent stage and I do not know why.

Comment: This does not seem to be possible with the `javafx.stage.FileChooser` class, as it is not customizable. You may need to implement a custom file chooser instead. We cannot even use `keyEvent.getSource()` to determine that the key was pressed while `FileChooser` was focused.

Comment: The problem seems to be the `FileChooser` is closed when `ESC` is _pressed_. By the time the `ESC` key is _released_ the `FileChooser` has closed and the `Stage` has regained focus. This also means that the `FileChooser` is not the source of the event, but rather whatever `Node` has focus when the `Stage` becomes focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve it. You are correct that if you close the FileChooser using either escape or ALT+F4 the event will be propagated, but you need to think which event will? if you have a look **only** the `KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED` will. So if you just add an event filter recording when the key was pressed you can find out when you pressed the escape ( or alt+f4 ) in your main stage or in your FileChooser

So more or less you are trying to find out if the `KEY_PRESSED` was handled by FileChooser or not. If it was, then the `KEY_RELEASED` will also be handled from FileChooser otherwise we trigger the KeyEvent in our main app.

Here is an example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private boolean captureKeys = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button browseBtn = new Button("Browse File System");
        browseBtn.setOnAction(ae -> {
            captureKeys = false;
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(browseBtn), 500, 200));

        stage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
            captureKeys = true;
            // For debug
            // KeyCode keyCode = keyEvent.getCode();
            // System.out.println("KEY_PRESSED on Stage : " + keyCode);
        });

        stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyEvent -> {
            if(captureKeys) {
                KeyCode keyCode = keyEvent.getCode();
                System.out.println(keyCode);
            }
        });

        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.show();
    }
}
```